# Applied setText method but activity is blank

Tags: java, android, methods, parameters, textview

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to pass arguments from one method to another in order to finally have text in my activity but when I run the app, it appears to be blank.

Here's my Java code:

```
package com.example.bhroo.bhrawiijava;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.R.id.message;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public int calculatePrice() {
        int lamia = 5;
        int newQuantity = lamia * 3;
       priceMessage(newQuantity);
        return newQuantity;
    }

    public String priceMessage(int aly) {
        String message = "el order haiib2a be " + aly;
        displayText(message);
        return message;
    }

    public void displayText(String kimo) {
        TextView orderSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ahmed);
        orderSummaryTextView.setText(kimo);
    }


}
```

and here's my XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bhroo.bhrawiijava.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ahmed"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just declaration of method will not change anything,
You need to call them first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must call to your method from you want, if you want you can call it from onCreate, just add this to your onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Add this
    calculatePrice();
}
```

my english is too bad and i'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onCreate`-method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int price = calculatePrice(); 
    priceMessage(price);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not making any call to the method you want to use. In your `OnCreate()` make a call to `calculatePrice();`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         calculatePrice();

    }
```